# Workaround for pdfcomment not working lualatex

Tags: luatex, pdfcomment, linuxfedora

> This is a very localized issue affecting Fedora 25 users with
>   `texlive.x86_64  6:2016-30.20160520.fc25`

I have a one year old document that after upgrading Fedora 25 doesn't compile anymore. I determined that the combination of `lualatex` and `pdfcomment` is problematic.

A simple document like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
blah
\end{document}
```

Does not compile with LuaLaTeX

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
```

by giving this error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./fusion.out) (./fusion.out)
! Undefined control sequence.
\PDF@SetupDoc ...pstringB {\@baseurl }\pdfcatalog 
                                                  {/PageMode/\@pdfpagemode \...

l.5 \begin{document}
```

Do you know of a workaround or option I have to pass to `pdfcomment` to make it work?

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me, but in general \RequirePackage{luatex85} before \documentclass is worth a try.

Comment: as Ulrike says, `luatex85` package will define `\pdfcatalog` but it should not be needed with an up to date texlive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for your answer, I get the same error with `luatex85`. The `pdfcomment` version is `2016/03/26 pdfcomment.sty v2.3b - Josef Kleber (C) 2008-2012, 2015-2016]` and `luatex` is `0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)`.

Comment: luatex85 defines `\pdfcatalaog` so you can't get that undefined message if you use `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as first line. but as I say with an up to date texlive you should get no error even without that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ah you are right I am getting a different error now `! Use of \@dt@getdate doesn't match its definition.
\pdfcreationdate ->\pdffeedback 
                                creationdate`. Do you know who defines `\@dt@getdate`?

Comment: @alfC `datetime` I'd guess (which isn't used in the example posted)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `datetime` solved it, but I am not using it explicitly, `pdfcomment` seems to do it internally, see my solution below. Also, what is better `RequirePackage` or `usepackage` for this type of workaround.

Comment: You can't use `\usepackage` before `\documentclass` so `\RequirePackage` is better.

Comment: @JPi, so the suggestion is that workaround packages code should go before `\documentclass`? Like this `\RequirePackage{datetime}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}\documentclass{article}...`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution proposed by @DavidCarlisle, **for my particular combination of versions `luatex 0.95.0` and `pdfcomment 2016/03/26 v2.3b`**. (may not be general, see comments.)

First add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` (or `\usepackage`?) and you will still get this new error `! Use of \@dt@getdate doesn't match its definition. \pdfcreationdate ->\pdffeedback creationdate`.

Then add `\RequirePackage{datetime}` (or `\usepackage`?) and the minimal example will compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{datetime}
\RequirePackage{luatex85} 
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to have a weird combinbation of new and old packages! Update to `pdfcomment` v2.4. It has a compatability fix for `luatex` >= v0.85. Furthermore it uses `datetime2` instead of the obsolete `datetime`. Your solution can't be regarded as general solution. Your MWE works perfectly with on up-to-date LaTeX distribution.

Comment: @Josef, probably I do. This is an upgraded Fedora 25 distribution. `dnf` reports `texlive.x86_64                                           6:2016-30.20160520.fc25`. This could be useful to a Fedora user.